# Android Message / Handler Mechanism - Is it safe?

Tags: java, android, handler, messaging

I'm using Bluetooth for data communication but it is just a note, not directly attached to my question. Remote device sends me packet of 5 to 10 bytes per millisecond. I'm classifying them and send to main activity via messages. 
In sender:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
Message msg;
if(something)
{
    bundle.putSerializable("data", aObject);
    msg = myHandler.obtainMessage(1);
}
else
{
    bundle.putSerializable("data", bObject);
    msg = myHandler.obtainMessage(2);
}
msg.setData(bundle);
mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

In handler;

```
switch (msg.what)
{
    // aObject
    case 1:
        AObject aObject = (AObject) message.getData().get("data");
        break;
// bObject
    case 2:
        BObject bObject = (BObject) message.getData().get("data");
        break;
    ...//There are 15 cases like that
}
```

After sometime I'm getting ClassCastException. I double checked that I'm sending correct *what* values with related data. I'm thinking that, while I'm handling message in handler, it is being overwritten in sender part. Because obtainMessage gets a message from global message pool. So, after checking msg.what, the data part of the message is changed in sender and I'm getting ClassCastException.

My question is; am I right in my thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Message should only get reused after the recycle method is called on it. This is done by the Handler/Looper for you after the handleMessage method runs on it.